# Filling in a database

Tags: sql

Let's say we have a database with the following two tables: books and authors.

The authors table has columns: id, name.
The books table has columns: id, title, author_id (refers to the authors table).

I add new books into the database manually, but I'd like to write a simple sql script to automate this task. Can I avoid looking up author_id by author name in the authors table (can this step be done by a database)? What I want is to enter the book title and the author name (i.e. I don't want to do looking up author_id first), something like this:

```
//script.sql
INSERT "A quick guide to SQL", "Philip Collins"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SELECT statement together with an insert:

```
insert into books (title, author_id)
select 'A quick guide to SQL', a.id
from author a
where a.name = 'Philip Collins';
```

This assumes that the author name is unique, otherwise it will insert multiple rows into the `books` table.

Note that in SQL, string constants are enclosed in single quotes (`'`), double quotes (`"`) are for identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view:

```
create view v_books as
    select b.*, a.name
    from books b join
         authors a
         on b.author_id = a.id;
```

This is a stored query and can be used like a table.

Comment: I suppose I failed to make my question clear enough. I want to be able to add a new book by writing a title and a name (of an author) instead of writing a title and an author_id. Can I somehow achieve this?

Comment: You can not. You need to do a look up to get the author name using author id.